# Cannot assign a value of type String to type UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a problem with my code:

```
var pwd = "okok"
@IBAction func SendPwd(sender: AnyObject) {

    if CreatePassWord = pwd {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: nil)

    }
```

When I do this I get the error below:

> Cannot assign a value of type String to type UITextField with the " 
>   if CreatePassWord = pwd " line...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Assign the `text` property of the text field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a UITextField is not a String. Set it's text property (which is a String) instead of the UITextField itself.

```
if CreatePassWord.text == pwd {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: nil)

}
```

EDIT: Since you're likely doing comparison, not assignment, you want to compare the two strings, not assign pwd to the UITextfield.

Comment: OP almost certainly means to do a comparison rather than assignment in the `if` statement.